# Parallel enrichment with spring integration - initial thread lost

Tags: spring-integration

We have the following spring integration flow:

> jms message-driven channel adapter -> ... -> pub/sub channel -> 3
>   enrichers subscribed -> aggregator -> ...

Each of the enrichers has `task-scheduler` specified, so they are working in parallel.

Unfortunately such approach does not work fine because original JMS thread is lost.

I expected `jms-message-driver-channel-adapter` and `aggregator` to run in the same thread, but `aggregator` (and following handlers) run in "last" enricher thread.

How can I achieve this? I don't see this written anywhere in `spring-int` docs.

**Added after Gary's reply**

I decided to implement this in more natural way:

```
<int:service-activator method="enrich" input-channel="in" output-channel="out">
  <bean class="com.xxx.ParallelEnricher" p:timeoutMs="10000">
    <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
    <constructor-arg>
      <list>
        <bean class="com.xxx.Enricher1" />
        <bean class="com.xxx.Enricher2" />
        <bean class="com.xxx.Enricher3" />
      </list>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

Where ParallelEnricher is a reusable class which calls "Future taskExecutor.submit(Runnable)" for each enricher and handles timeouts.
May be I'm missing something but it would be nice to configure parallel operations on the same message like this:

```
<int:service-activator method="enrich" input-channel="in" output-channel="out"
                       timeout="10000" task-executor="taskExecutor">
  <list>
    <bean class="com.xxx.Enricher1" />
    <bean class="com.xxx.Enricher2" />
    <bean class="com.xxx.Enricher3" />
  </list>
</int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add a gateway mid-flow; that way, the JMS thread will wait for the reply from the ultimate consumer - which has to return "something" (just leave off his `output-channel` and the framework will return the reply to the gateway, where it can be discarded)...

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="fromJMS" output-channel="nullChannel" 
    ref="gw" />

<int:gateway default-request-channel="myPubSub" />
```

Just make sure the final consumer (presumably somewhere after the aggregator) sends a reply (it doesn't matter what it is; it will be discarded by sending it to the `nullChannel`).

Note that the thread will wait indefinitely by default; you will need extra logic if you need to time out and rollback the message.

Another solution would be to add a fourth subscriber, a simple service that `receive()`s from a `QueueChannel`. Again, the ultimate consumer sends a message to trigger the release. You would need a header enricher ahead of the pub/sub to add a new `QueueChannel` header to each message (`<int:header name="myReleaseTriggerChannel" expression="new ...QueueChannel()"/>`; the final consumer sends "something" to that header (could be a simple router).

This solution requires a little user code (to receive from the queue), but it's easier to handle the timeout this way.

Comment: Hi Gary. Thanks for describing possible solutions. I suspected that there is no straightforward way to do this. Honestly I don't even like that pub/sub channel and aggregator are present in this flow. When we doing such kind of task manually (without spring-int), we just have: thread pool executor, futures and wait logic in caller thread. All this stuff makes XML configuration overcomplicated and hard to understand. I decided to implement this in more natural way (will update original post with details)